# How would I loop over all the checkboxes in my form?

Tags: c#

I'm working on an application for school in which you can add games into a list who's information is later displayed on the screen.

In the form, there are 8 checkboxes and each one represents a console. You can check the consoles on which the game is available.

As a result I want to get an array of booleans that contains 8 different values, one for each console.

I believe that my code is not compact and there should be a much better solution. Is there a way that I can loop over the code instead of writing some code for every single checkbox?

This is currently what I have.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    bool[] platforms = new bool[8] { false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false };
    if (checkBox1.Checked) 
    {
        platforms[0] = true;
    }
    if (checkBox2.Checked) 
    {
        platforms[1] = true;
    }
    if (checkBox3.Checked) 
    {
        platforms[2] = true;
    }
    if (checkBox4.Checked)
    {
        platforms[3] = true;
    }
    if (checkBox5.Checked)
    {
        platforms[4] = true;
    }
    if (checkBox6.Checked)
    {
        platforms[5] = true;
    }
    if (checkBox7.Checked)
    {
        platforms[6] = true;
    }
    if (checkBox8.Checked)
    {
        platforms[7] = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you familiar with Lambda Expressions.. I would look into something like that.. or how to loop through controls using the `Controls` class..?

Comment: Your form should have a property `Controls` which contains a reference to every control that is registered on the form. Loop over it and check the type (*ignore non checkbox controls*). You can then get the name and based on the name get the numeric value of the last character(s) and use that to set the index based on the controls value (based on the logic above).

Comment: Your form has `Controls` collection. Iterate over it filtering out `CheckBox`. To every `CheckBox` associate `Tag` property to semantics of it.

Comment: something like this you can do to get you started also do a simple google search..there are literally 100's of different working examples 
`foreach(var cb in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
{
  //do stuff check if Checked then set platforms[] ...
}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming it is Windows Forms, you could do it like this:

```
int index = 0;
foreach (Control Con in this.Controls)
{
    if (Con is CheckBox)
        platforms[index++] = ((CheckBox)Con).Checked;
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that this will only work if the checkboxes are immediate children of the form.  It will not recurse into panels, groupboxes, or any other container control.

Comment: Additionally, I recommend using `Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()` instead of looping through all controls and checking the type yourself.  Not a biggie, but it's more compact.

Comment: Thanks @adv12 and Igor, didn't have much info o how the controlers where placed, but you are both absolutely correct! Greetings!

Comment: Great solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `this.Controls.OfType`, but you need to save its result in a bool array so I think this code works for you:

```
 bool[] platforms = new bool[8] { false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false };

      var controls = this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().ToArray();

      for (int i = 0; i < controls.Length; i++)
      {
        platforms[i] = controls[i].Checked;
      }
```

If you usually use this kind of method you can create the extension for Form Like this

```
public static class FormExtension
  {
    public static CheckBox[] GetCheckboxes(this Form form)
    {
      return form.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().ToArray();
    }
  }
```

And just call like:

```
var checkboxes = this.GetCheckboxes();
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but what have you done to guarantee that `platforms[0]` will be set to the value of  `checkbox1.Checked`, `platforms[1]` will be set to the value of `checkbox2.Checked`, and so on?  Seems like you're relying on the order in which the controls appear in the `Controls` list, which has no necessary correlation to the checkbox names.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to preface this with, you should put all of your checkboxes inside a GroupBox or a Panel , or some sort of container control.  That way you know which checkboxes are iterated over.  Because wouldn't it be silly if you added another checkbox you didn't want in this list and all of a sudden change your functionality?

Given what I've seen though, this is what I'd recommend.  It won't dynamically grow as you add new controls, but it will only iterate over the checkboxes you want.  If you throw your Checkboxes in a container use the other answer!

```
bool[] platforms = new bool[8] 
{
    checkBox1.Checked,
    checkBox2.Checked,
    checkBox3.Checked,
    checkBox4.Checked,
    checkBox4.Checked,
    checkBox5.Checked,
    checkBox6.Checked,
    checkBox7.Checked
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to go one step further in regards to what @adv12 had stated in case controls are nested / inside other containers this is pretty straight forward and I works well to

```
private void SetCheckedValues()
{
    Action<Control.ControlCollection> func = null;
    func = (controls) =>
    {
        foreach (Control control in controls)
        {
            if (control is CheckBox)
            {
                (control as CheckBox).Checked();
                //set your other values to True creating a counter variable outside the foreach and 
                //incrementing it inside here
            }
            else
            {
                func(control.Controls);
            }
        }
    };
    func(Controls);
}
```